# Google Firebase как загрузить список данных без класса посредника realtime database?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database, realtime

Итак, имеется вот такая база:

[image: База :3]

Обычно что бы загрузить данные (по крайней мере в туторах, которые я смотрел) нужно сначала создать класс а-ля "класс-посредник" в объект которого будут ложиться наши данные из базы. Причем имена полей "класса-посредника" должны совпадать с именами в базе данных полей пользователя (gL3m69oQfkRQo1unZv5MUI0kl202 - айдишник пользователя);

```
class Data
{
    string first_name; // псевдокод
    string nickname; 
}
```

Причем, если я ошибусь в классе посреднике и напишу одно поле, например,  firstName, а не first_name, то все рухнет по крайней мере у меня все приложение крашнулось.

Поэтому встает вопрос как это обойти?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно указывать правильный ключ к данным

first_name - это ключ в котором расположена информация. А вы пытаетесь, если я вас правильно понял, найти информацию по ключу firstName.

Comment: Не так. Нужно выгружать данные в какой-нибудь универсальный контейнер независящий от названий ключей в бд.
Я хочу выгрузить все данные не используя класс посредник. 

Например в бд добавятся данные пользователя по мимо nickname, first_name, появится ключ  last_name, А класс посредник считывает только  nickname, first_name, которые, например, добавляются в ArrayList, т.е. при появлении вб записи last_name: пупкин, они не считаются.

Comment: Как вы получаете данные с firebase? Покажите это в вопросе